# Angular Material Autocomplete multiple checkbox item style

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material

Does anyone know how to set the autocomplete multiple checkbox item height in Angular Material?

I want to like this

[Line item height 18px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJgCY.png)

But it shows this while using multiple checkbox

[Line item checkbox height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9Whf.png)

Here is my sample code https://stackblitz.com/edit/components-issue-s5kjcj?file=src/app/example-component.css

Answer (score 0):

You need to add CSS in the way like class to the element mentioned as tag

```
.mat-option {
  font-size: x-small;
  min-height: auto;
  line-height: 18px;
}
```

Comment: I added CSS class to mat-autocomplete, mat-option or mat-checkbox but not work.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it in this way. Not sure it is good approach. Just post it if someone may have the same problem.

1. Create custom theme and add CSS below. i.e. custom-theme.scss

   mat-checkbox {
   .mdc-form-field {
   font-size: x-small;
   height: 20px;
   }
   }
2. Insert custom theme into angular.json

   "styles": [
   "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
   "src/styles.scss",
   "src/themes/custom-theme.scss"
   ],

Below is my sample by adding the CSS into global src/styles.scss:

[Work sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/components-issue-s5kjcj?file=src/styles.scss)